# Ubuntu on Microsoft Surface Book 2, the battery percentage doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, microsoft, surface

I have just installed Ubuntu on my laptop but I can't see the battery percentage. How could I see it?

Comment: what version of ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: I've done a web search, and it seems that this is a recurring problem on surface book 2s.  I have not found an answer, but I will try to help you.  it seems that there is no fix.

Comment: I was wondering about if it could be shown in the terminal but I don't know how

Comment: From basic research, this seems to have been a kernel bug that was patched out a while ago. Have you updated your computer? If not, I would suggest you do so.